# Search through queryset with one to one field

Tags: python, django

I have two models `UserDetails` and `User`.

I have a simple search that checks if the string is in one of the fields.
My problem is that I don't know how to access the one-to-one field in the queryset below to search through this as well.

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    related_name='detail')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

search = 'John Doe'
User.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=search) |
    Q(desc__icontains=search) |
    Q(__detail_details=search) . # how to do this?
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use double underscores (`__`) with the `related_name` on the left. So:

```
User.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=search) |
    Q(desc__icontains=search) |
    Q(detail__details=search)
)
```

Or in case you want to add an `__icontains` lookup:

```
User.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=search) |
    Q(desc__icontains=search) |
    Q(detail__details__icontains=search)
)
```

Given `search` is thus `'John Doe'` we will return `User` objects where the `name` contains `'John Doe'`, the `desc` contains `'John Doe'`, or the related `UserDetail` object its `details` column contains `'John Doe'`.

The double underscore can be seen as a way to look "through" relations, and thus access columns of these related objects. You can chain these together in a `rel1__rel2__rel3__some_field__some_lookup` fashion.